# ¿Existe un sitio en Stack Exchange sobre electrónica?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange

¿Existe un sitio en Stack Exchange sobre electrónica?

Además, ¿se pueden crear etiquetas propias?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Los títulos de las preguntas deben ser breves pero descriptivos.
2. La red de sitios se llama [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com)
3. Para destacar que Stack Overflow en español y otro sitios de la red son diferentes a otros sitios solemos decir que no son un foros.
4. En la red hay sitio sobre electrónica en se llama [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).
5. En la red no hay el concepto de propias,  sólo etiquetas. Más detalles en [¿Qué son las etiquetas, y cómo debo usarlas?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)
6. Por cierto, cada publicación debería versar sobre un tema específico.

Comment: Creo que `Electrónica != Electrical Engineering` (independientemente del idioma)

Comment: @Flxtr: Te sugiero acceder al sitio, seguir el recorrido y consultar lo que es on-topic allá :P

Comment: La [página de inicio](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) veo que dice "Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for electronics and electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts. "